# reading from socket serval times the same thing in diffrent places

Tags: java, sockets, connection

im reading an object from a socket by ObjectInputStream. suppose that im send from the main server the object myobjec to the client. in the client side there is 2 threads which reads objects all the time. Is it posible that the two threads will read the same myobject? im trying to this but im getting "connection by peer error".

Comment: A connection reset by peer message means that the site you are connected to has reset the connection. This is usually caused by a high amount of traffic on the site, but may be caused by a server error as well. More [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21295765)

Comment: Both threads wrapping the same socket Input stream? Read it once, and then pass it to each thread that needs it.

Comment: @tmwanik I hesitate to contradict IBM but 'connection reset by peer' most usually means that you have written to a connection that has already been closed by the other end, as per what it says at the end of that citation, which doesn't look very expert to me. I'm not aware that it has any connection with high traffic specifically, except insofar as that provokes delays which in turn provoke users to browse away from the page being served.